# Windows 11 black screen instead of blue

Tags: windows-11, reboot, background

Maybe a silly question, but I would just like to know this, is this an error or what. I just installed Windows 11 (upgraded from Windows 10 Home) and it works fine. Just some backgrounds colors are black as default instead of blue. Windows 11 is activated.

It looks like this:

[image]

Is this backgrounds normal for Windows 11? I can't get any other color.

Comment: I have noticed that Windows has changed Ctrl Alt Del, Updates and other screens to a universal white text on black background. So that is just the new way,

Comment: So, this is normal. Thanks.